# Некоректное переобразование типов данных MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

прохожу курс на Stepik по SQL. Мне нужно узнать отношение двух значений, на первом скрине, я сделал задачу на компиляторе степика(MYSQL), а на втором у себя локально(MSSQL). Почему на втором скрине отображаются int ?

[image: MYSQL]

[image: MSSQL]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

Это преобразует рассчитаное значение в тип данных DECIMAL.

```
SELECT CAST(x AS DECIMAL(15,4))/ y
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Почему на втором скрине отображаются int ?

Лучше спросите себя, с чего вдруг там появиться чему-то кроме int?

Все операнды имеют тип int, значит и результат будет int.